# Quick way to reject a list in Python

Tags: python, list, validation, iterable

I have a list of items in python, and a way to check if the item is valid or not. I need to reject the entire list if any one of items there is invalid. I could do this:

```
def valid(myList):
    for x in myList:
        if isInvalid(x):
           return False
    return True
```

Is there a more Pythonic way for doing this? You could filter it, but that would evaluate all the items in the list, when evaluating just the first one could be sufficient (if it is bad)...

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The typical way to do this is to use the builtin [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function with a generator expression

```
if any(isInvalid(x) for x in myList):
   #reject
```

The syntax is clean and elegant and you get the same short-circuiting behavior that you had on your original function.

Comment: Nice!, didn't know of such a thing!

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- I prefer to change the logic of the program.  If any is invalid, reject the list (rather than what OP currently has -- if not any is invalid, keep the list).  But that's ultimately for OP to decide :)

Comment: `if any(…): return False` directly replaces the loop with `return False` in the OP's code. Compressing it to `return not any(…)` is a further step that might be worth doing, but I think this is a more obvious answer to the question.